# Changing all files to .txt from folder and all subfolder in Mac terminal

Tags: macos, terminal

I'm trying to change all file in a folder and subfolder to .txt from the terminal. I'm doing this one folder at a time but could I do all folder at one time and subfolders? 
Here is what I'm using:
 `for i in *; do mv "$i" "$i.txt"; done`

Answer (score 0):

I founds it. you need to be a in the root directory and run:                 find . -type f -exec mv '{}' '{}'.txt \;